# Getting "array is not JSON seriazable" in django

Tags: django, json

I am getting this error in django. How can I get a better look at the offending piece of data and perhaps delete it? Or what similar type is JSON serializable?

This error came out of the blue, my site was working and now it won't load because of this error.

```
Traceback:
File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  100.                     response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/var/www/site/instance/src/server/site/site_core/views.py" in os_show
  1193.     return json_result(result)
File "/var/www/site/instance/src/server/site/../site/includes/jsonutils.py" in json_result
  25.     return HttpResponse(serialize(result, ensure_ascii=True))
File "/var/www/site/instance/src/server/site/../site/includes/jsonutils.py" in serialize
  10.     return json.dumps(object)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.4/site-packages/simplejson/__init__.py" in dumps
  230.         return _default_encoder.encode(obj)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.4/site-packages/simplejson/encoder.py" in encode
  200.         chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.4/site-packages/simplejson/encoder.py" in iterencode
  260.         return _iterencode(o, 0)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.4/site-packages/simplejson/encoder.py" in default
  177.         raise TypeError(repr(o) + " is not JSON serializable")

Exception Type: TypeError at /os/show/1/
Exception Value: array([ 0.63266369]) is not JSON serializable
```

Comment: Getting any JS errors in the console?

Comment: @Josh nothing alarming. Just this `GET` error - `HTTP 500 INTERNAL SERVER ERROR` from this request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to serialize an array.  When I try to do simplejson.dumps(my_array), I get the same error.  Does you view create an array?  If so, can it convert it to a list or something else that works with dumps?

Answer (score 0):

I would set a breakpoint (if you are using a debugger) or log some output in your views.py at 1193. Have a look at `object` that gets passed to `json_result()`.

It may be that one of the object attributes is that array.